# How to stop scrolling of iframe parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

When I use a scroll in the model iframe the parent iframe is also starts to scroll when the model iframe comes to its bottom. I need to stop the crolling of the parent iframe. How can I do that?

```
<div id="myModal"  data-keyboard="true" data-backdrop="static" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: hidden;" >
        <div class="modal-content" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
        <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow-y: hidden; max-height:85%;" ></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

image of my my webpage:

[image]

Comment: Give us a live demo! or link of your website.

Comment: Hide your `body`'s overflow when your popup appears and remove it again when done.